# Are there any good add-ons for managing categories on the publish screen?

Tags: add-on, categories

I have a channel that will require lots of editing (adding and selecting) of many categories and want to make this as simple a process as possible for the client. I also need to require that only one category can be selected at a time (unlike the multiple on the Categories tab).

Is there a decent fieldtype add-on that allows for managing categories, not just selecting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the add-ons really did the trick so I ended up just dragging the categories field onto the Publish page from the Toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

You can try my Category Field addon which should do exactly what your looking for:

> This field type allows you organize your category groups as you would any other custom field type anywhere on your publish entries form. Additionally a filtered input is provided for long category lists.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-field

Comment: Nuno, does your fieldtype save the category selection as 'native' categories (e.g. writes to the exp_category_posts table)?

Comment: Yep all native functionality.

Answer (score 3):

This fieldtype is often overlooked, but I find for single-category entries, Lonely Cat by Wouter Vervloet to be amazingly simple and effective.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/lonely-cat

The advantage of Lonely Cat is in its ability to be instantly grasped by the user, and in the fact that it selects only one category at a time, though it can be configured to also select all parents of that category, as well.

Comment: Can the user add Categories from the Publish screen as well?

Comment: Seems this is only for category selection and not management.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use Playa for your categories.
That will make it easy for your client to edit/add or delete categories.

1. It looks nice!
2. ease of use. (http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/templates)
3. You can add a lot of extra fields to a single category.
4. Restrict that the client can select only one option (in this case a category).

Answer (score 1):

The Category Field add-on mentioned by Nuno looks like it may cover it.

The Solspace Primary Category add-on provides another option for managing category selection, though likely not as in-depth as you are looking for.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/primary-category

Sometimes I also use Tags as an alternative for categories.

http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tag/

http://www.devdemon.com/tagger/

Comment: The Solspace Tags UI is *exactly* what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to have one feature I require: restricting to only one tag per entry.