# Hiding specific categories from the publish tab

Tags: categories, publish-layout

Within a category group, I've got about 10 categories that don't need to be seen by anyone but myself.

If I had realised this while planning the site, I would have created them in a separate category group to keep them slightly isolated.

However, my content admins would still be able to see it. How can this be addressed? (It would be cool if category groups were also available within publish layouts to hide/show!)

Comment: check out this thread. Sounds like something you can try http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/930/are-there-any-good-add-ons-for-managing-categories-on-the-publish-screen/931#comment1127_931

Comment: Not sure if there is an add-on written for this, but I'm sure it would be pretty simple to write a basic Accessory that would hide these categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a "don't need to be seen" situation, give them a "Don't Use" category parent and stick 'em at the bottom of the list. If it's a "can't be seen" situation, that's a different animal.

Comment: Dylan as the only answer, you win the prize for now!

Comment: Not much of an answer, but it's worked for me in the past.

Hiding/showing category groups based on member groups would be a great feature, though.